# How to set width of mat-table column width

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]I'm using this code across the application. In someplace we have 6 some other places we have 8 based the conditions columns may increase or decrease can anyone help me on how to fix the columns widths

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-table">
           <ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of objectKeys(columnHeader)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] !== 'Select'">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{columnHeader[tableData]}}    </th>
           </ng-container>
           <ng-container *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] == 'Select'">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><mat-checkbox (change)="getAllRecordSelected($event)"></mat-checkbox></th>
           </ng-container>

           <ng-container *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] !== 'Select' && columnHeader[tableData] !== 'Action'">
              <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element">
                <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let data of element[tableData]">
                    <div class="datacontent"> <span ngbTooltip="{{data}}" placement="top"> {{ (data?.length > 40)?(data | slice:0:40)+'...':(data)}}</span> </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </td>
           </ng-container>
           <ng-container *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] == 'Select'">
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                 <mat-checkbox [checked]="element.checked" (change)="getRecord($event, element)"></mat-checkbox>
              </td>
           </ng-container>
           <ng-container *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] == 'Action'">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <button name="cancel" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="cancelButton($event, element)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button mat-raised-button color="primary" name="resend" (click)="resendButton($event, element)" class="btn btn-default">Resend</button>
         </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
           <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="objectKeys(columnHeader); sticky: true"></tr>
           <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(columnHeader);" (click)="getRecordClicked(row)"></tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) on `style.width` as follows:

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [style.width]="'200px'">{{columnHeader[tableData]}}</th>
```

To get rid of the horizontal scrollbars, you should also define the following in the CSS.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-dynamic-rows-and-columns-q8ch4g?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.html).

Comment: I tried with min and max-width its working only in some cases. But I want to fix this issue dynamically without a scroll bar for a table. Because of a common component, it is not working as expected

Comment: @PDSSandeep: I updated my answer and added some more information. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I think widths are fixed manually in the given example. I will try this approach dynamically. If any alternate solution plz post it. Thanks for your time